# Is it possible to implement Google's Place on a custom map on my website?

Tags: google-maps

I have to implement a map on a website, with google map. 
For the moment, I've put a marker, with a window that opens and displays custom html. 
Like here: 
http://www.montreuxjazzcafe.com/fr/cafe/geneva?page=contact (click on the pink link on the right, under "Carte")

But my client asks if it is possible to have, in the window, the informations relative to the place which is registered in Google's DB, exactly like here: 
http://maps.google.ch/maps?q=Montreux+Jazz+Caf%C3%A9+Geneva&hl=en&ie=UTF8&georestrict=input_srcid:9e080c8d2d0b5303&view=map&cid=8032887087538302764&hq=Montreux+Jazz+Caf%C3%A9+Geneva&t=m&z=17&iwloc=A<

So my question is: is it possible to add a Google Place on a custom google map, on this website? If yes, how do I implement it and where do I get the ID of the place?

Thank you in advance for your help!
David

Answer (score 0):

Google has an API for places.  Check this out... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Place details, specifically...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details